# Migrate file doesn't detect a custom process plugin

Tags: migrations, plugins

I'm working in a migration from a custom CMS to Drupal.
In a first step I have migrate the paragraphs; now, I'm trying to migrate the nodes. All the fields are filled except the paragraph field.

I have debugged the code and verified the sub process is running, but not my custom plugins.

This is the migration file.

```yaml
# Migration configuration for experience content.
id: ptur_migrate_experience
label: Experience
audit: true
migration_tags:
  - gestiona_ciudad
  - gestiona_ciudad_experience
migration_group: content
source:
  plugin: ptur_migrate_experience
  key: migrate
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: experience
  title: titulo
  int_zipcode: codpostal_quedar
  body: descripcion
  text_address: direccion_quedar
  id_experiencia: id_experiencia
  paragraphs:
    plugin: sub_process
      source: paragraphs
      process:
        target_id:
          plugin: ptur_migrate_experience_stage_id
          source: '@id_experiencia'
          field: target_id
        target_revision_id:
          plugin: ptur_migrate_experience_stage_id_revision
          source: '@id_experiencia'
          field: target_revision_id
      date_range/value: fecha_inicio
      date_range/end_value: fecha_fin
      int_user: id_usuario
      # image:
      decimal_price: precio
      # campo geofield no aplica en experiencias
      # geofield_meet:
      # content_route:
      int_invitation: max_usuarios
      link: url_reservar
      int_user_max: max_usuarios
      status: activado
```

This is one of the plugins, whose scaffold has been built with `drush gen migrate:process`.

```php
namespace Drupal\ptur_migrate_experience\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\Component\Transliteration\TransliterationInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a ptur_migrate_experience_stage_id plugin.
 *
 * Usage:
 *
 * @code
 * process:
 *   bar:
 *     plugin: ptur_migrate_experience_stage_id
 *     source: foo
 * @endcode
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "ptur_migrate_experience_stage_id",
 *   handle_multiples = TRUE
 * )
 *
 * @DCG
 * ContainerFactoryPluginInterface is optional here. If you have no need for
 * external services just remove it and all other stuff except transform()
 * method.
 */
class PturMigrateExperienceStageId extends ProcessPluginBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The transliteration service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Component\Transliteration\TransliterationInterface
   */
  protected $transliteration;

  /**
   * Constructs a PturMigrateexperienceStageId plugin.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   The plugin configuration.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin ID.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Component\Transliteration\TransliterationInterface $transliteration
   *   The transliteration service.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, TransliterationInterface $transliteration) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->transliteration = $transliteration;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('transliteration')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    return $this->query($value);
  }

  /**
   * Metod to get the new paragraphs id.
   *
   * @param int $value
   *   This is the value id_experiencia, table experiencia.
   *
   * @return void
   *   Return destid1.
   */
  protected function query($value) {

    Database::setActiveConnection('migrate');
    $migrateDB = Database::getConnection();
    $query = $migrateDB->select('etapa_experiencia', 'ee');
    $query->fields('ee', ['id_etapa', 'id_experiencia']);
    $query->condition('ee.id_experiencia', $value, '=');
    $result1 = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result1 as $result) {
      Database::setActiveConnection();
      $query = \Drupal::database()->select('migrate_map_ptur_migrate_paragraph_stage_for_experience', 'm');
      $query->fields('m', ['destid1']);
      $query->condition('m.sourceid1', $result->id_etapa);
      $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
      $return[] = ['target_id' => (reset($result)->destid1)];
    }
    return $return;
  }

}
```

I don't understand why the plugins are not called.